# Why is there extra spacing at the top of my div after vertical centering?

Tags: html, css

I've been using the vertical spacing trick for all my div's with text in them, and while it made the vertical spacing go from 0% to 90% perfectly centered, it's leaving more space at the top of the tip then the bottom. It's doing it on every single div I used it on. I've tried setting padding/margin to 0 but nothing happened. Not sure what specifically is causing this. It's pretty irritating. Anyone have an idea?

Live example -

https://jay-portfolio.herokuapp.com/

Pic of issue -

http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/spacing-incorrect_zps0hjolnyv.png

HTML -

```
<section id="about" ng-controller="aboutController">    
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row about-row">

      <div class="about-left col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      </div>

      <div class="about-right col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="about-content">
          <div class="about-content-title">
            <h1><strong>I'M JAY.</strong></h1>
          </div>

          <div class="about-content-info">
            <p ng-if="about.firstParagraph">{{ about.paragraphOne }}</p>
            <p ng-if="!about.firstParagraph">{{ about.paragraphTwo }}</p>
          </div>

          <div class="about-button">
            <button ng-if="about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success" ng-click="about.switchParagraph()">MORE =></button>
            <button ng-if="!about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success"><a href="##skills">VIEW SKILLS</a></button>
          </div>

          <div class="about-personal-info">
            <h4>Email: jaybittner@gmail.com</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="about-icon">
            <a href="{{ profile.url }}" ng-repeat="profile in about.profiles"><img ng-src="{{ profile.icon }}" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

CSS -

```
#about {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,97,65,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,97,65,1)), color-stop(7%, rgba(54,135,95,1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(36,123,85,1)), color-stop(53%, rgba(0,97,65,1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(34,121,84,1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(54,135,95,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(54,135,95,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#006141', endColorstr='#36875f', GradientType=1 );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #101010;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

#about .container-fluid, #about .row {
  height: 100%;
}

.about-left {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../../images/jay-ocean.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-right: 3px solid #101010;
}

.about-right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.about-content {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.about-content-title h1{
  font-size: 3.1vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.6vh;
}

.about-content-info p {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.7vh;
}

.about-button button {
  margin-bottom: -0.1vh;
}

.about-personal-info h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0.7vh;
}

.about-button button {
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  background-color: #101010;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
}

.about-button a {
  color: gray;
}

.about-personal-info h4 {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-icon img {
  height: 3.5vh;
  width: 1.75vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  margin: 3px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .about-left {
    height: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }

  .about-right {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .about-content {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .about-content-title h1 {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }

  .about-content-info p {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }

  .about-button button {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }

  .about-personal-info h4 {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }

  .about-icon img {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: JsFiddle or live example?

Comment: provide the rendered HTML

Comment: https://jay-portfolio.herokuapp.com/

@Joost

Comment: Answer turned out to be that I had to remove 'margin-top' from all the h1's in each page. That extra space above was ruining the look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that I needed to add 'margin-top: 0' to .about-content-title h1. There was an extra space above the h1 which was causing the content div to have extra blank space at the top of it. The div was centered but had blank space inside of it. This fixed it.

```
.about-content-title h1 {
  font-size: 3.1vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.6vh;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}` to your stylesheet and then edit your div tags from there. Good luck.

Comment: Explain what, how, why? This makes your answer clear to other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css trick for vertical center a div in another div:

```css
#outerdiv {
   width: 700px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: 400px;
   position: relative;
   background: #eee;
   text-align: center;
}
#innerdiv{
   width: 240px;
   height:100px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -120px;/* half of #innerdiv width*/
   margin-top: -50px;/* half of #innerdiv height*/
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerdiv">
  <div id="innerdiv">Centered div</div>
</div>
```